# is there a problem with how i'm logging to my log file

Tags: python, python-logging

i am trying to save some logs to a file using a function that takes in a custom message and logs that message to the log file alongside a timestamp. However, nothing seems to be entered into the log file. My script and the log file are in the same directory level

This is what i tried

```
LOG_FILE='log.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE, level=logging.INFO)

def createLoggingInfo(message:str):
    timestamp = time.ctime()
    log_message = f'{timestamp} {message}'
    logging.info(log_message)
    logging.info(f'\n\nWriting from {getWorkingFile()} to {FILENAME} was successful')
    
createLoggingInfo('i am writing something')
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code works for me.

Comment: The directory containing your script is not necessarily the current working directory, which is where `log.txt` will be found. E.g., if you run `python somedir/myscript.py`, the log file will end up in the directory that contains `somedir`, not in `somedir`.

Comment: @Unmitigated or is it in the way getWorkingFile() is used here ?

` ` `import os
from inspect import getsourcefile
def getWorkingFile():
    current_script_path = os.path.abspath(getsourcefile(lambda: 0))
    return current_script_path

` ` `